# Drawing rows from one dataset based on probabilities given in other dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have two datasets. First one contains probability of occurrence of every "Group" in the data set for particular period and combination of 4 socio_demo variables combined in "socio_demo" column. Column "Group" have only 4 groups but there are 11 periods and 144 socio-demo combinations.

| Period | Group | socio_demo | Probabilities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 1 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 60 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 2 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 20 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 3 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 10 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 4 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 10 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 1 | 20yo_West_old_2child | 50 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 2 | 20yo_West_old_2child | 20 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 3 | 20yo_West_old_2child | 25 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 4 | 20yo_West_old_2child | 5 |

Second one contains:

| Period | ID | socio_demo | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 1 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.1 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 2 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.11 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 3 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.69 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 4 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.14 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 5 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.98 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 6 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.89 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 7 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.45 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 8 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.1 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 9 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.4 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 10 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.3 |

Taking 1st row as an example, I want to:
for each row from 1st dataset take the probability of belonging to each of 4 groups (from "Group" column) and randomly draw 60% of rows from 2nd dataset that are 20yo_West_old_3child and have this period 01.2021-03.2021 and with new column "Group" assign them given group (1).

I want my output to look like this:

| Period | ID | socio_demo | Weight | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 1 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.1 | 1 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 2 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.11 | 1 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 3 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.69 | 2 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 4 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.14 | 1 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 5 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.98 | 4 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 6 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.89 | 1 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 7 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.45 | 3 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 8 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.1 | 1 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 9 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.4 | 2 |
| 01.2021-03.2021 | 10 | 20yo_West_old_3child | 0.3 | 1 |

Thank you for any hints and for helping out with this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
Here's an updated answer that should scale better for larger data. It takes advantage of the rolling joins enabled by dplyr 1.1.0, now on CRAN.

Here, I pick a number from 1-100 for each row of df2, and use that to pick the match from df1 which relates to that point in the cumulative probabilities for each Period/socio_demo.

```
library(dplyr) # using the newly release v1.1.0, now on CRAN

df1_cuml <- df1 %>%
  group_by(Period, socio_demo) %>%
  mutate(prob_cuml = cumsum(Probabilities))

df2 %>%
  mutate(sample_int = sample(1:100, size = nrow(df2), replace = TRUE)) %>%
  left_join(df1_cuml, 
            join_by(Period, socio_demo, closest(sample_int >= prob_cuml)))
```

---

Original answer:

I imagine there's a tidier way to do this with base R, but here's a sort of brute force approach, where I join the two tables, make as many copies of each df1 row as the Probability percentage, and then randomly pick one from each Period/ID combination:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
df2 %>%
  left_join(df1) %>%
  tidyr::uncount(Probabilities) %>%
  group_by(Period, ID) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result

```
Joining, by = c("Period", "socio_demo")
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   Period             ID socio_demo           Weight Group
   <chr>           <int> <chr>                 <dbl> <int>
 1 01.2021-03.2021     1 20yo_West_old_3child   0.1      1
 2 01.2021-03.2021     2 20yo_West_old_3child   0.11     2
 3 01.2021-03.2021     3 20yo_West_old_3child   0.69     1
 4 01.2021-03.2021     4 20yo_West_old_3child   0.14     2
 5 01.2021-03.2021     5 20yo_West_old_3child   0.98     4
 6 01.2021-03.2021     6 20yo_West_old_3child   0.89     1
 7 01.2021-03.2021     7 20yo_West_old_3child   0.45     1
 8 01.2021-03.2021     8 20yo_West_old_3child   0.1      1
 9 01.2021-03.2021     9 20yo_West_old_3child   0.4      1
10 01.2021-03.2021    10 20yo_West_old_3child   0.3      2
```

---

input data

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                   Period = c("01.2021-03.2021",
                              "01.2021-03.2021","01.2021-03.2021",
                              "01.2021-03.2021","01.2021-03.2021","01.2021-03.2021",
                              "01.2021-03.2021","01.2021-03.2021"),
             Group = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L),
               socio_demo = c("20yo_West_old_3child","20yo_West_old_3child",
                              "20yo_West_old_3child","20yo_West_old_3child",
                              "20yo_West_old_2child","20yo_West_old_2child","20yo_West_old_2child",
                              "20yo_West_old_2child"),
     Probabilities = c(60L, 20L, 10L, 10L, 50L, 20L, 25L, 5L)
       )


df2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                   Period = c("01.2021-03.2021",
                              "01.2021-03.2021","01.2021-03.2021",
                              "01.2021-03.2021","01.2021-03.2021","01.2021-03.2021",
                              "01.2021-03.2021","01.2021-03.2021",
                              "01.2021-03.2021","01.2021-03.2021"),
                ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L),
               socio_demo = c("20yo_West_old_3child","20yo_West_old_3child",
                              "20yo_West_old_3child","20yo_West_old_3child",
                              "20yo_West_old_3child","20yo_West_old_3child","20yo_West_old_3child",
                              "20yo_West_old_3child","20yo_West_old_3child",
                              "20yo_West_old_3child"),
                   Weight = c(0.1,0.11,0.69,
                              0.14,0.98,0.89,0.45,0.1,0.4,0.3)
       )
```

Comment: Isn't their desired output stochastic? Or does my answer have the wrong structure?

Comment: Hello, thank you for an answer, although my dataset is too big for this approach, R doesn't allow to compute this, I got an error: Long vectors are not yet supported. Requested output must be less than 2147483647. You have any idea how to omit that error?

Comment: Updated with another approach using the new release of dplyr with rolling joins. It should be much more efficient for larger data.